# Regex matching not working

Tags: regex

I am trying to match SiteCode:980807, PumpID:2, NozzleID:2, SaleDateTimeStart:2016-07-08T07:30:16+01:00, SaleDateTimeEnd:2016-07-08T07:31:12+01:00, SaleVolume:25, TransactionID:1 to ([a-zA-Z0-9]+:[,\s])* . This is not working. Is anyone have an idea.
Thx,
Nipuna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the value after the colon, and I assume the comma is mandatory but space is optional. In that case it becomes: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+:[^,]+(,[\s]*|[\s]*$))*`

Comment: Thx a lot. appreciate your quick response